# Problem with creating integration from the config

Tags: magento2, module, integration

I have been having trouble completing tutorial on [creating integration from the config](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//howdoi/webapi/integration.html).

I believe I followed all the steps correctly. Please help me find the reason why the integration won't appear as expected.

### Project structure

Placed in `vendor` directory of Magento root directory.

```
somevendor
└── module-somemodule
    ├── Setup
    │   └── InstallData.php
    ├── composer.json
    ├── etc
    │   ├── integration
    │   │   ├── api.xml
    │   │   └── config.xml
    │   └── module.xml
    └── registration.php
```

I decided to name my example vendor as `Somevendor` and module as `Somemodule` just for testing purposes.

### File contents

#### composer.json

```
{
     "name": "Somevendor_Somemodule",
     "description": "create integration from config",
     "require": {
            "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
            "magento/framework": "2.0.0",
            "magento/module-integration": "2.0.0"
     },
     "type": "magento2-module",
     "version": "1.0",
     "autoload": {
            "files": [ "registration.php" ],
            "psr-4": {
                 "Somevendor\\Somemodule\\": ""
            }
     }
}
```

#### registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Somevendor_Somemodule',
    __DIR__
    );
```

#### etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Somevendor_Somemodule" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Integration"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

#### etc/integration/api.xml

```
<integrations>
    <integration name="testIntegration">
        <resources>
            <!-- To grant permission to Magento_Log::online, its parent Magento_Customer::customer needs to be declared as well-->
            <resource name="Magento_Customer::customer" />
            <resource name="Magento_Log::online" />
            <!-- To grant permission to Magento_Sales::reorder, all its parent resources need to be declared-->
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales" />
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_operation" />
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_order" />
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions" />
            <resource name="Magento_Sales::reorder" />
        </resources>
    </integration>
</integrations>
```

#### etc/integration/config.xml

```
<integrations>
   <integration name="TestIntegration">
       <email>someone@example.com</email>
       <endpoint_url>http://example.com</endpoint_url>
       <identity_link_url>http://example.com/identity</identity_link_url>
   </integration>
</integrations>
```

#### Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Somevendor\Somemodule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Integration\Model\ConfigBasedIntegrationManager;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
        /**
         * @var ConfigBasedIntegrationManager
         */


        private $integrationManager;

        /**
         * @param ConfigBasedIntegrationManager $integrationManager
         */

        public function __construct(ConfigBasedIntegrationManager $integrationManager)
        {
                $this->integrationManager = $integrationManager;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
                $this->integrationManager->processIntegrationConfig(['testIntegration']);
        }
}
```

### Local setup

#### phpinfo()

I couldn't put entire config as post length is limited to 30000 characters but I will put specific information if requested.

```
PHP Version => 5.5.30

System => Darwin rutherfordium.local 15.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Dec  4 2015 19:25:34
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-apxs2=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs' '--with-config-file-path=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--disable-debug' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ctype' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-shmop' '--disable-sigchild' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-wddx' '--with-gdbm=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-jpeg-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-png-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-freetype-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-zlib=yes' '--with-zlib-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-openssl=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-xsl=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-ldap=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/bitnami/xamppunixinstallerstack-osx-x64/src/imap-2007e' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-gettext=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-mssql=shared,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-sybase-ct=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-mysql-sock=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient' '--with-mcrypt=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-mhash=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-mbstring=all' '--with-curl=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-exif' '--with-bz2=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-sqlite=shared,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-sqlite3=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-libxml-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--enable-soap' '--with-xmlrpc' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pgsql=shared,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/' '--with-iconv=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/postgresql' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-icu-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-phar' '--enable-zip'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20121113
PHP Extension => 20121212
Zend Extension => 220121212
Zend Extension Build => API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20121212,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.5.30

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
...
```

#### Magento version

2.0.4

### Building

Clean-up the build

```
rm -rf var/di
```

Or

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/*
```

Launch the upgrade

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Build

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Note that I am using `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php` instead of simply `php` because I want to be sure this is same runtime as locally running server.

I completed several other examples, for custom API endpoint and observers, those worked fine with same approach and debug logging, only integration causes trouble.

### Obtained results

Integration does not appear in the admin panel as tutorial suggests it should.

### Attempts to explain

I failed to put logger in the `InstallData.php` script as I tried to determine if it is being launched or not. The reason why it didn't work is actually a subject for opening a separate issue.

Maybe someone could advise if there is a better way to test that, it would be a good start.

Comment: Once you check app/etc/config.php then you can go to   `setup_module` table and check whether your module `data_version` is listed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, in `app/etc/config.php` I don't even have `setup_module`, there only is an array of modules and it doesn't even figure on that list.

Comment: check your module name in ` config.php ( Somevendor_Somemodule )` , if it it is there the next step is go to your mysql Database and  table name `setup_module` , in that table search for your module and version number

Comment: Thanks @krishnaijjada it also was helpful as it helped to realised the module was in fact not installed. Important remark is that without removing the db record you mentioned, the `Setup/InstallData.php` will NOT be launched after eventual update.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, this GitHub issue helped:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4023

Another remark: suggested directory `vendor` does not trigger the install, I had to put it in `app/code` directory.

Comment: can you share your code please  I am having the same problem and couldn't fix it anyhow.